# Is it possible to loose state in kafka state store when using at least once processing in a stream application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

For every message I processes in my kafka streams application, I update a state store.

If I use at least once processing in the stream application, is there a possibility to lose an update done to the state store due to a particular message?

For an example, if a rebalance happens when 10th message is being processed by a particular stream task, and the stream task gets assigned to a different process, is there a chance to lose the update which should be done to the state store as a result of processing the 10th message?

Comment: You cannot lose events in "at least once" processing. Did you mean "at most once"?

Comment: @OneCricketeer it is "at least once". I wanted to know whether the processing guarantee applied to the state stores as well.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals enough, but I would hope that the offset isn't committed until after the state store is written to

Comment: @OneCricketeer I was also thinking the same. Hope the state store writes and offset commits are sent to the cluster sequentially in the correct order, so that there is no chance for the offset to be committed but the state store is not updated.

Comment: _but the state store is not updated_ - Is this a specific problem you are having right now? If so, maybe it would help if you showed your code and streams-config

Comment: @OneCricketeer No. I did not observe such behavior, but wanted to know whether there is a possibility.

Comment: So, let's say a rebalance happened, and the new task has no state. Then it would need to consume from the beginning before it can process new records, and therefore wouldn't depend on what's being processed elsewhere. Now, if you have something that is actively querying the store while it is in the middle of rebalancing, then you might miss out on something, unless the query is blocked, but that seems to be separate from what you're asking

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think if a stream task is assigned from one instance to another due to rebalancing, it would continue from the last committed offsets of the input topics. Please correct me if I am wrong.